# How can i parse a xml file from the http URL without downloading the file and print the desired string?

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, sed, xml

Hi i am not sure if this is possible, i have checked over google many options.

For example if i have a http URL which has xml content : http://server.com/lastBuild/api/xml

content would be something like below and `<building>false</building>` this can be present in multiple lines

`<action/>
<building>false</building>
<displayName>mercury_system</displayName>
<duration>1606128</duration>`

Can i parse the same http url without downloading the content to local and print the last occurrence of 'false' string in `<building>false</building>`?

Comment: *print the last occurrence of 'false' string* - just print `false`? Show the desired output

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes, just print the last occurence of 'false' string

Comment: if it would not be the last it will still be `false` string. What is the point of printing `false`?

Comment: Not sure of any cool Command line programs you can use to do this.. But i know a script (python, perl, etc) or something java based (using JDOM) to do this...

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest oops i missed it, it might be 'false' or 'success'. Need to print the string present in <building>false/success</building>

Comment: `curl 'http://example.com/path/to/xml' | grep -Eo '<building>[a-z]+</building>' | tail -n1`?  That said, XML is not regular and you should not be using regular expressions to parse it.  You should use a DOM parser or other XML parser.  Also, what kind of XML specification uses "false" or "success" as boolean values?

Comment: @DopeGhoti i am using this case for a Jenkins pipeline build, i need to take the build result output and use it to start another build. My pipeline is a critical one and i have checked for options within cloudbees

Comment: @DopeGhoti i am trying the same with <result>Success/false/ABORTED</result> but it doesn't return anything. this is strange

Comment: I use https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/misc/xpquery for this sort of thing but it downloads the file first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to 'download' it to a file first. You can temporarily download it as part of a pipeline

Use [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/download.php)  to parse xml

```
curl 'http://example.com/lastBuild/api/xml' 
| xmlstarlet sel -t -c "//building[last()]/text()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sed alternative:

```
$ curl -s 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gevasiliou/PythonTests/master/test.xml' |tac |sed -n '/<building>/{s/<.[^>]*>//g;p;q}'
      success
```